# React Native: error Expected ; -- where's the typo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I feel like this is a relatively minor typo but I just can't find it when I compare to the answer key.
The error I receive is: [image]

The code can be found here: 
https://github.com/g4m3r2/weather1

Thank you!

Comment: Read up on the differences between class components and functional components. The usage is pretty different. You're mixing pieces from each.

Answer (score 2):

you are using function you don't have to add render () ,when you remove it issue will be fixed. render is used for class.

Comment: Are you referring to the render here?

  handleUpdateLocation =(city) => {
    this.setState ({
      location:city,
    })
  }
    render () {
    return (
When I delete it, it gives me another error which states TransformErrror SyntaxError in App.js Unexpected token (27:6) pointing to an empty space in front of keyboardavoiding view

Comment: after removing render function your first error is removed ... now this is another error and it is pointing towards keyboardavoiding view ...